# HighCharts : How to REMOVE (or) HIDE a certain data POINT in Series?

Tags: highcharts, point, series

In HighCharts, let's say I have a data series. As usual like this:
[image]

Then how do I **NOT DISPLAY (or HIDE) a point**? Like this:
[image]
*(This is Photoshopped)*

### Reason

Because of in some charts, there are some factors that there are points with **NOT APPLICABLE** value. (Data unknown or something like that) **BUT NOT ZEROS**. *(ZEROs still means a value)* So that i can not even put as the Zero while the value is N/A (or) unknown. Otherwise, it will confused the user, and then it is dangerous.

Even more worse thing is, this is health related charts. I can't let the reader misunderstood.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set `null` to the point value.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/X3zEq/